# How can I control traffic, when I use "for" in locust?

Tags: python-3.x, locust

When I use "for" in locust, I do not know why the "req/s" is too high.

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def start_congche(self):
        filename = 'D:\测试\项目\精励评分\从车评分/阳光压力测试数据.csv'
        with open(filename) as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for test in reader:
                self.client.post("/DataPreFillServer/DataPreFillProductService", first +test["vin"] + vincode +test["vehicle_code"] + vehicleCode + end)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    host = "http://10.10.6.12:8080"
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 1000
```

[image]

But, if I do not use "for", everything is ok....

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    
         @task(1)
         def start_congche(self):
             self.client.post("/DataPreFillServer/DataPreFillProductService", first + vincode + vehicleCode + end)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the class of queue..
each time from the queue to take the value.

```
user_data_queue = queue.Queue()
filename = 'XXXXXXXX.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for test in reader:
        data = {
        "vin": test["vin"],
        "vehicle_code": test["vehicle_code"],
        }
        user_data_queue.put_nowait(data)

 try:
    data = self.locust.user_data_queue.get_nowait()
 except queue.Empty:    
    exit(0)

 self.client.post("/DataPreFillServer/DataPreFillProductService",payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why you are seeing 20 requests/second in the first approach is the for loop is executing *multiple* post requests each time one of the five Locust users attacks the system. Depending how large the file is, let's say its 20 iterations, that means each user executed likely in parallel 20 times and it the test ended.

Take a look at your start and end times, the first test finishes in ~8 seconds while the other one takes around 30 something.

In the second test, five locust users execute a single post request per user and has to go back and continue executing one at a time until 100 requests are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much~